# Iterating JSON key value pairs over another JSON file and create a new json as per the output

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a JSON file from two JSON files. Here I am reading the key value pairs from `input.json` and searching the matches in the `secondary.json` file and finally dumping the output to a new json file.

In the output of `test.py` I am expecting

```
{'tire1': {'source': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']},
 'tire6': {'source': ['test10', 'test21', 'test33']}}
```

instead of

```
{'tire1': {'source': ['test10', 'test21', 'test33']},
 'tire6': {'source': ['test10', 'test21', 'test33']}}
```

But do not know what's wrong.

test.py

```
import json
import re

def findkeysvalues(inputDict, key):
    if isinstance(inputDict, list):
        for i in inputDict:
            for x in findkeysvalues(i, key):
               yield x
    if isinstance(inputDict, dict):
        if key in inputDict:
            yield inputDict[key]
        for j in inputDict.values():
            for x in findkeysvalues(j, key):                
                yield x

def process_JSON_value(jsonFileInput, parentInputKey, key):
    with open(jsonFileInput) as jsonFile:      
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        Dict = { }
        for i in data:
            if i == parentInputKey:
                Dict[i] = data[i]
        return list(findkeysvalues(Dict, key))

def createRulesJSON():
    
    with open("input.json") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)

    Dict = { }
    
    rules_items_source = list(findkeysvalues(data, "source"))
    for p in data:
        Dict[p] = { }
        for i in rules_items_source:
            x = re.findall("\w+", i[0])
            sourceItems = process_JSON_value("secondary.json", x[0], "compname")
            Dict[p]['source'] = sourceItems
    print(Dict)
createRulesJSON()
```

input.json

```
{
    "tire1": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'TEX' | YYYYYYY | join }}" ],
        "dest": [ "{{ Microservice.host }}" ],
        "port": "555"
    },
    "tire6": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'REP' | LLLLLL | join }}" ],
        "dest": [ "{{ Microservice.host2 }}" ],
        "port": "555"
    }
}
```

secondary.json

```
{ 
    "client": {
        "name": "anyname"
    },
    "PEP": {
        "tire2": {
            "tire3": {
                "compname": "test1"
            },
            "tire4": {
                "compname": "test2"
            },
            "tire5": {
                "compname": "test3"
            }
        }
    },
    "REP": {
        "tire2": {
            "cmpname": "vendor1",
            "tire3": {
                "compname": "test10"
            },
            "tire4": {
                "compname": "test21"
            },
            "tire5": {
                "compname": "test33"
            }
        }
    },
    "Microservice": {
        "host": "ttttttttttttttttttttt",
        "host2": "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
    }
}
```

Comment: You seems to want "TEX" to map to "PEP". But I see no code that takes care of that.

Comment: Could you come back to us? Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- Your nested loops in `createRulesJSON` create a Cartesian product on `data`. The first loop gets all keys from the data, and the nested loop extracts the three-letter code from all data. So you will combine one key with a code that was extracted from the other key's data. There is no attempt to keep these two informations associated, yet that is what you need.

  To fix that, change this:

  ```
  rules_items_source = list(findkeysvalues(data, "source"))
  for p in data:
  ```

  To:

  ```
  for p in data:
      rules_items_source = list(findkeysvalues(data[p], "source"))
  ```
- From the expected output it seems that you want to map the code "TEX" (in the first file) with the code "PEP" (in the second file). There is nothing that maps these two codes to eachother.

  To fix that, I will just assume that you'll correct in one of your files the code to match the other code.